# Where to start theremin project

Tags: circuit-design, math, music

I am studying electronics and would like to design a theremin that uses discrete components.  I have read that RF oscillators such as those needed for a theremin are not likely to work if built on a breadboard and so I do not have plans to build the circuit I design.  (I do not have building experience beyond breadboards and I do not have any "proper" equipment.  This is a pen-and-paper project only.)

Based on this block diagram:
[image] it looks like all I need are 6 sub-circuits, and each of them appears to my novice eyes to require only a small handful of components.

I have studied...

- circuit analysis (Thevenin, mesh, etc)
- oscillators
- transistor amplifiers
- op-amps
- filters

I am reasonably good at algebra and some calculus.

This is a two-part question.  First, are there things I haven't studied yet that I need to study before starting, and second, which of these sub-circuits is the most difficult given my skill level?  I'd like to start there and "fail fast" in my learning.

NB: i understand that the block diagram I shared lacks the volume control antenna.   I'm fine with designing a simple theremin without volume control.

EDIT: I am strongly considering designing the project to produce a line-level output similar to an electric guitar, NOT drove a speaker.

Comment: You didn't mention "mixers" in your list of things that you have studied.

Comment: @Andyaka correct, I have not studied mixers.

Comment: Folks often find digital circuits easier than analog. It is possible to use logic devices to do the oscillator and mixer blocks. It *is possible* to even use digital techniques to do the audio amplifier. If you intend to use analog circuitry for the audio block to drive a loudspeaker, that might be most difficult. Digital circuits, and digital signal processing are not on your list. Be aware that digital signal processing has become ubiquitous.

Comment: @glen_geek I'm also trying to learn circuit design, so analog components seem more attractive.   But I hear you that driving a speaker would be a big challenge

Comment: also @glen_geek I think you could phrase the bit about driving a speaker as an answer

Comment: @glen_geek, You heretic! "digital theremin" is an abominable idea.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Ha, perhaps digital theremins should be played only by robots, like **Dactyl** from **OpenAI**. But how do you teach a robot musical aesthetics? Does my answer below (using ancient analog technology) allow me any redemption?

Comment: @nuggethead I note you said "line level" and excluded "speaker." Also, you said "paper design" and thereby excluded actually building one. So are you thinking of a discrete design that excludes *analog* ICs? (Let's assume you don't want to use digital and/or MCUs.) In short, something that doesn't use ICs, is analog by nature, and where you can show Theremin behavior per your block diagram that would simulate satisfactorily? Or would an entirely analog use of an analog IC be okay? Or am I missing your goals?

Comment: @jonk I don't know much about ICs, but if you are suggesting novice level components like a 555 or LM386 audio amp that would be fine

Comment: @nuggethead I'm thinking about the MC1496 as the mixer. It's really nice for that job.

Comment: @jonk I've never heard of it but I'll look it up.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't get why you think driving a speaker is a challenge. Driving a speaker will be the easiest part. Guitars also are not even line level devices, they are even weaker instrument level devices. You want a line level output and it really is just different amplitude than instrument level.